# Cannot connect to Server--error after Civi update to 5.41.0

Tags: webform-civicrm, error

Drupal 7.82
Civi 5.41.0

We just updated Civi to 5.41.0. Since the update when we go to a contact and click the contribution tab, we often get a "Network Error: Unable to reach the server" message.

It seems to be certain contacts work and certain ones do not. I have not figured out a connection between those that fail/work.

We have tried it on multiple computers and browsers and the problem in consistent with which donors work/fail.

I checked our .htaccess file and I uncommented the www rewrite rule. I tried it both ways (not at the same time). I looked at our civicrm.settings.php file and the base url is without the www so I left htaccess to rewrite to without. Still not working.

**In Chrome and Firefox I get the following error:**
VM879:1 GET https://secure.radiusinternational.org/civicrm/contact/view/contribution?reset=1&force=1&cid=4297&snippet=json 500 (Service unavailable (with message))

**In Civi logs:**
[warning] Deprecated join alias 'contact' used in APIv4 get. Should be changed to 'contact_id' Caller: Civi\Api4\Query\Api4SelectQuery::autoJoinFK

**In Drupal logs:**
LOCATION    https://secure.radiusinternational.org/civicrm/contact/view/contribution?reset=1&force=1&cid=4297&snippet=json

REFERRER    https://secure.radiusinternational.org/civicrm/contact/view?reset=1&cid=4297

MESSAGE TypeError: Argument 1 passed to CRM_Financial_BAO_Order::setPriceSetID() must be of the type int, null given, called in .../civicrm/CRM/Financial/BAO/Order.php on line 902 in CRM_Financial_BAO_Order->setPriceSetID() (line 465 of .../civicrm/CRM/Financial/BAO/Order.php).

Comment: I figured out that this is related to Webform-CiviCRM. I will post there.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm/issues/3236621

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is having null in civicrm_line_item:price_field_id & price_field_value_id
If a donor has one historical contribution that is missing the price field id & price field value id, then you cannot access their contribution tab.

The fix is to fill in the missing fields, a couple of options:

1. LineItem Edit extension and do them one by one
2. Use the API Explorer so you can update them in large groupings
3. SQL update queries

For # 2&3, MAKE A BACKUP of your database before you start in case you change more than you wanted to.

Answer (score 2):

Posted in Webform CiviCRM Drupal Issue queue:

<< >>

Webform CiviCRM indeed has not been specific about price_field_id or
price_field_value_id in the past - b/c CiviCRM core has been 'fetching' these
automatically. When there is a ton of price_fields though (both visible and
hidden), the fetching may not produce the correct result or no result at all.

I have already started drafting a better line item branch for Webform CiviCRM
to be more specific. Using it for 1 client at this time. It will need to get
finalized in the 8.x-5.x version first and secured with a test before we can
backport that to 7.x-5.x